# ng-include not recognizing appended version number

Tags: angularjs, html

I appended version number to all of my templates under routeProvider so that it will load the latest templates every time the version number changes. It works just fine until I noticed that there is still one more template that needs to be appended, and that`s the sidebar-menu that was found on ng-include. I appended version number to it using this code

```
<div ng-include = "'views/sidebar-menu.html?v={{VERSION_NO}}'"></div>
```

I successfully changed the version number, however, it is still not reflecting my latest changes to the menu template. Any idea why this doesn`t work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-include` takes an expression, so you don't need interpolation syntax `{{`. Instead, you can set the full string on the scope.

```
$scope.sidebarTemplate = 'views/sidebar-menu.html?v=' + VERSION_NO;
```

Now you can do `<div ng-include="sidebarTemplate">`

Comment: Awesome. It works! But why does the code I posted above not working though? When I check at inspect element, it shows that I got the path that i wanted through that code(i.e. views/sidebar-menu.html?v=1.1). It just that it`s not reflecting the changes on the template.

Answer (score 3):

Reason it didn't worked is you put variable name inside single quotes so it will be considered as string .

Try:

```
<div ng-include = "'views/sidebar-menu.html?v='+VERSION_NO"></div>
```

This will parse your variable and give you required version.You don't need paranthesis {{ }} as it evaluates expression, hence will evaluate your variable automatically